# def function : if nothing selected , return a list of all the objects

Tags: python, function

i'm trying define a function that return a list when i specify an object, and it returns a list of all the objects in the scene with *_control when i don't specify anything..
that's my function but it doesn't work....
i'm working with maya then..

```
from maya import cmds

def correct_value(selection):

       if not isinstance(selection, list):
            selection = [selection]
            objs = selection
            return objs

       if not selection : 
            objs = cmds.ls ('*_control')    
            return objs
```

when i don't specify anything it returns an error :

> Error: line 1: TypeError: file  line 1: correct_value()
>   takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

what's wrong ??

Comment: Can You post example of code how this function is run?

Comment: What's the confusion? You specified that `correct_value` takes a single argument, then called it without one.

Comment: One who will interested in this question in future can be confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def correct_value(selection=None):
     if selection is None:  # note that You should check this before  
                            # You wil check whether it is list or not
        objs = cmds.ls ('*_control')    
        return objs

    if not isinstance(selection, list):
        selection = [selection]
        objs = selection
        return objs
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you wrote your function with a required argument. Therefore, you have to pass the argument. You can write it so the argument is optional by specifying the value that will be used when nothing is passed:

```
def correct_value(selection=None):
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a parameter to be optional, you need to provide a default value:

```
def correct_value(selection=None):
    # do something

    if selection is None: 
        #do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle a default parameter even if it might be `None`

```
def correct_value(*args):
    if not args:
        objs = cmds.ls ('*_control')    
        return objs
    elif len(args) == 1:
        selection = args
        objs = selection
        return objs
    else:
       raise TypeError # ...
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach and works well for a single argument. I usually go with a specially-defined default value in such cases (such as a class that's not used for anything else).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really useful pair of patterns for this kind of stuff:

```
# always return a list from scene queries (maya will often return 'none' 
def get_items_named_foo():
     return cmds.ls("foo") or []  # this makes sure that you've always got a list, even if it's empty


# always use the variable *args method to pass in lists
def do_something(*args):
    for item in args:
        do_something(item)  # args will always be a tuple, so you can iterate over it

# this lets you do stuff like this without lots of boring argument checks:
do_something (*get_items_named_foo())
```

If you use both of these tricks consistently, you can transparently handle cases where your maya queries have returned None instead of a list

As an aside, you can mimic the default maya behaviour (where passing no arguments uses the current selection) like this:

```
def work_on_list_or_selected(*args):
   args = args or cmds.ls(sl=True) or []
   for item in args:
       do_something (item)
```