# Maya useRayTraceShadows - Python error NoneType object is not iterable

Tags: python, maya, light, nonetype, shadows

i am trying to set the ray trace shadows in maya on/off via a function, this function reading from a text scroll list ( which is the lights in the scene ) however its giving me the following error  line 106: 'NoneType' object is not iterable #

wird thing i've used the same code to set attributes to the light(s) and its working, but not for this one, code is below, any help will be appreciated.

Ubuntu 12.04 & Python 2.7

def RT_ShadowsOff():

```
selectedLights = cmds.textScrollList ("lgtList", query = True, selectItem = True)

for lgt in selectedLights:
    cmds.setAttr(lgt+".useRayTraceShadows", False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonetype is not iterable almost always means you asked for a list and Maya gave you back a 'None' instead of an empty list.  You can get around the *error* in the above code with

```
selectedLights = cmds.textScrollList ("lgtList", query = True, 
                                      selectItem = True) or []
```

Which will always return a list, although the list will be empty if nothing is selected in your UI.

For more on how to handle list-type returns in Maya, see my answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940971/def-function-if-nothing-selected-return-a-list-of-all-the-objects/16947681#16947681)

Comment: thanks alot for the prompt reply, your modification to the code worked perfectly ... so is it a bad practice to do it that way for the rest of the code ? ... i mean should i go back and modify the other functions even tho they are working ?

Comment: I try to do it everywhere, since it makes for much cleaner code: every 'or []' saves you at least one 'if <thing-that-should-be-a-list>' somewhere else, and (as I mentioned in the other post) it makes it easy to handle variable arguments consistently.   OTOH - if it ain't broke...  :)   If this solved the problem for you remember to mark it answered so others see it in future

Comment: once again ... thanks a lot dude ... I'll mark it answered for sure :)